# Erlang: Reading environment variables and assign them to a constant

Tags: macros, erlang, environment-variables, constants

I want to test an application and decided to pass configuration parameters to my erlang application with using environment variables.
Currently I am reading them as a macro with `-define(PARAMETER1, os:getenv("PARAMETER1")).`

However, with this implementation, the variable is read with every call (And I am not sure about the performance of this call).

Is there a way to read environment variables only once when starting the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define` is a macro, so what's in the macro will be placed in the actual code every time you use the macro. You just need to call `os:getenv/1` in a function once, store it in the state and pass it to supervisors and other modules that need that environment variable, [for example](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/humbundee/src/hbd_app.erl#L30):

```
start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    case get_cfg() of
        {error, _} = Err -> Err;
        Cfg -> start_sup(Cfg)
    end.

get_cfg() ->
    try
        hbd_cfg:setup()
    catch
        throw:Term -> {error, Term}
    end.

start_sup(Cfg) ->
    case hbd_sup:start_link(Cfg) of
        {ok, Pid} ->
            hbd_event_logger:add_handler(),
            {ok, Pid};
        Other ->
            {error, Other}
    end.
```

In this example the configuration is read once in `get_cfg/0` and then passed to the supervisor, which will pass it to supervised workers.

Comment: This is for reading it once and passing it to the worker. But how to access these information? How to store them to have easy access without passing them from function to function.

I am writing an application in which I am listening to a raw socket and whenever a packet arrives I need the information which are configured in my os vars.

Comment: You could store the read value in ETS which can be accessed from any process. Or you could store it in a separate `gen_server` and ask the `gen_server` for the value every time you need it. There is no other way. Erlang was designed to be a functional language with no easy access to shared state. A function can only use data that has been explicitly passed to it or which it can query using other functions (in this case `os:getenv`, `ets`, dedicated `gen_server` or similar). This of course applies to dynamic data read while the program is running, not to static data known to the compiler.